# Gerar thumbnail de video em php

Tags: php

Queria pegar a thumbnail de um vídeo após o vídeo ter sido upado no site, já procurei um monte e só o que acho é sobre o ffmpeg e os "tutoriais" basicamente te dizem os comandos(não ensinam nem como instala). Teria alguma outra forma sem ser o ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11732732/2993657) no SO em inglês, você deve instalar o [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net). Após instalado, bastaria utilizar o seguinte código:

```
<?php

$frame = 10;
$movie = 'test.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail.png';

$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($movie);
$frame = $mov->getFrame($frame);
if ($frame) {
    $gd_image = $frame->toGDImage();
    if ($gd_image) {
        imagepng($gd_image, $thumbnail);
        imagedestroy($gd_image);
        echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'">';
    }
}

?>
```